# Atom - JSBeautify and JSLint don't agree about ternary line breaking

Tags: ide, atom-editor, jslint, js-beautify

I have JSLint and Atom-beautify (which I believe is a front-end for jsbeautify) installed in Atom. Generally that's pretty dandy, except that they bicker about ternary operators (I think that's the right term). So if I do

```js
  var theWindow = (thisObj instanceof Panel)? thisObj: new Window("palette", thisObj.scriptTitle, undefined, {resizeable: true});
```

JSBeautify will make it look like:

```js
var theWindow = (thisObj instanceof Panel)
  ? thisObj
  : new Window("palette", thisObj.scriptTitle, undefined, {resizeable: true});
```

And then JSLint will complain about bad line breaking.

[image]

I had a look at the JSBeautify documentation and the JSLint documentation, but I can't find any option for changing either's behaviour regarding ternary syntax. Can anyone tell me how I can change it so I don't have to manually reformat all my ternary functions every time I beautify my code? I don't mind which one prevails as long as they agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add option `"preserve_ternary_lines":true` in `.jsbeautifyrc`
The ternary line expression will no more be broken.

Related change from atom-beautify: [atom-beautify/pull/726](https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/pull/726)

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about `jslint` (“lint”), but the linter in use is actually `jshint` (“hint”.)

## jshint

Create a `.jshintrc` file and add the following rule to tolerate multi-line strings

```
{
  "multistr": true
}
```

You also *might* have to set `"laxbreak"` to true, this tolerates possibly unsafe line breakings. See the [example](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/examples/.jshintrc) for all available options

## jslint

Again, you can create a `.jslintrc` file to override the default options of [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/). Use the [example](https://github.com/tcarlsen/atom-jslint/blob/master/.jslintrc-example) as reference.

Comment: And that's why I asked the question. In the JSLint docs it says it's happy with the way JSBEautify does them, in fact the online jslint page complains *unless* you have the line break. Maybe it's just the Atom implementation of JSLint thats broken.

Comment: I just noticed you mix up `jshint` and `jslint`, so I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: You're right. I was new to the whole linting concept when I started and I installed JSHint instead of JSLint (I installed a few and deleted the ones that didn't seem to work, including JSLint which doesn't seem to do .jsx files). Since posting this I've now discovered JSCS , then discovered that that JSCS is deprecated, and now I've switched to ESLint, which does the beautifying and linting all together.